# Bayesion priors in ridge regression with scikit learn's linear model

Tags: regression, python, ridge-regression, scikit-learn

I'm using scikit learn's linear model to do [ridge regression](http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/0.8/modules/generated/scikits.learn.linear_model.Ridge.html).
Ridge regression penalizes parameters for moving away from zero. I want to penalize for moving away from a certain prior, with each parameter having a different prior.

Is this possible with scikit learn's linear model? I know there's a [BayesianRidge](http://scikit-learn.org/0.10/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.BayesianRidge.html) module there, but I'm not sure what it does.

Answer (score 13):

Ridge regression looks like:

$$
\min_{\beta}||Y-X\beta||^2 + \lambda_1 ||\beta||^2
$$

If you want to instead compute

$$
\beta^* = \arg\min_{\beta}||Y-X\beta||^2 + \lambda_1 ||\beta - \beta_0||^2
$$

I guess you could just turn this into shrinking towards zero using the new variable

$$\theta = \beta - \beta_0.$$

So you'd solve:

$$
\theta^*  := \arg\min_{\theta}||Y-X\beta_0-X \theta||^2 + \lambda_1 ||\theta||^2
$$

Then apply the change of variables again (i.e., $\beta^* := \theta^* + \beta_0$).

So to recap, if I have some black box function $\text{RidgeRegression}(Y,X, \lambda)$, I can use it to solve for an arbitrary prior $\beta_0$ simply by calling $\text{RidgeRegression}(Y-X\beta_0, X, \lambda)$.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, $\text{RidgeRegression}(Y - X \beta_0, X, \lambda)$ gives you $\theta^*$, but you want $\beta^*$, so you actually want to replace $\text{RidgeRegression}(Y, X, \lambda)$ with $\text{RidgeRegression}(Y - X \beta_0, X, \lambda) + \beta_0$.

Comment: This is what I have done, but the annoying thing is that the scoring is no longer correct. So either you need to keep the total sum of squares of $Y$ as opposed to $Y-X \beta_0$ on hand to manually re-calculate $R^2$, or you need to write some kind of wrapper around RidgeRegression. I'm not sure which to do. I guess that's similar to the fact that you need to keep the prior parameter vector $\beta_0$ on hand to add the fitted parameters to.

Comment: I ended up deciding to make wrapper, i.e. a new class that holds a private RidgeRegression object, and has its own `fit` and `score` methods that do some transformations before and after calling the respective RidgeRegression methods.

Answer (score 0):

What's posted in the only answer by Dapz does not do what it's supposed to do.
If I choose a value > 0 for any of the $\beta_0$, say the "i-th", the corresponding $\beta^*$ of "i" will be lower than with standard ridge regression, instead of higher as it should be (because we penalize for moving away from something > 0, instead of moving away from 0).

Comment: can you post some reproducible code?

Comment: Did you intend to write this as a comment beneath Dapz's reply? Also, I've merged your two accounts but you will need to register this one to to benefit from all the advantages of the Stack Exchange community.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work, implementing the solution suggested by others above:

```
def fit_with_prior(model, X, y, sample_weight=None, prior=None):
    """Fit a regularized model with a nonzero prior"""
    assert prior is not None, "you need to specify a prior"
    new_y = y - np.sum(prior * X, axis=1)
    model.fit(X, new_y, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    model.coef_ += prior  # modifying underlying model's coefficients
    # what about the intercept?
```

Initialize the `Ridge` model object as you normally would: `my_ridge = Ridge(alpha,...)`, and instead of calling `my_ridge.fit(X, y)`, call `fit_with_prior(my_ridge, X, y, prior=prior)`, where `prior` is a vector of length equal to the number of columns in `x`, being the prior values toward which you want to regularize. I think the intercept term is probably not penalized, and can thus be ignored for the purposes of this transformation (unless you explicitly added a column of constants to `X`, in which case it will be treated just like the other coefficients). I think it should also work for other regularized linear models, e.g. `ElasticNet`, as long as they use their `coef_` attribute to do prediction and scoring, as `Ridge` seems to based on my testing.